# PHP program perfect on localhost, won't work on live site

Tags: php, localhost

The following is actually an assignment for my php class. I worked it out on my localhost. Everything runs perfect on there, but when I upload it to my live site the logic gets all screwed up. It is the quintessential "Guessing Game" program. There are no errors reported.

The only problem is that, *when on the live server*, the user can enter **anything**  - even "1" and it shows that their entry is "too high".

Could this be a problem with my site's (fatcow) php settings? I think what's happening is somehow it is showing my session variable as "zero" for some reason, instead of the rand(1, 10) number. Why would this be happening? How can I fix it so that it works the same as it does on my localhost?

The code:

```
<?php

session_start();

error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$pageTitle = "Guessing Game";
include('includes/header.inc.php');

if (isset($_POST['finish']))
{
        unset($_SESSION);
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        die ('<h2>Congratulations</h2>
              <p>Your session has been reset.<br />
              Click <a href="guessingGame.php">HERE</a> to play again!</p>');
}
elseif (isset($_POST['guess']))
{
    $_SESSION['count'] = $_SESSION['count'] + 1;
    $guess = $_POST['guess'];
    if (!ctype_digit($guess) || $guess <= 0 || $guess > 10 )
    {
        echo'<p span class="italic">SORRY, that entry is invalid</span></p>';
    }
    else 
    {
        if ($guess == $_SESSION['num'])
        {
            die ('<h1>Hooray!</h1>
            <h2>You got it correct<br />
                And it only took you ' . $_SESSION['count'] . ' tries!</h2>
            <p>Click the button to finish:</p>
                <form action="guessingGame.php" method="post">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Finished" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="finish" value="true" />
                </form></p>');
        }
        elseif ($guess < $_SESSION['num']) 
        {
            echo '<h2>Sorry, that is incorrect.</h2>
                <p>Your guess is too LOW</p>';
        }
        else 
        {
            echo '<h2>Sorry, that is incorrect.</h2>
                <p>Your guess is too HIGH</p>';
        }               
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['num'] = rand(1,10);
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}
?>      
<h1>Please guess a number between 1 and 10</h1>
<p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
        <input type="text" name="guess" size="2" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</p>
<?php
include('includes/footer.inc.php');
?>
```

Comment: where is the link of ur live site ?

Comment: Are you sure that the session is saved?

Comment: Perhaps add a var_dump($_SESSION) statement to your site; and push that up to the Live version so you can take a look and see what the contents (if any) of your $_SESSION are and how that differs from what is on your localhost.

Comment: What version of PHP are your two hosts running? Also, is there any PHP code running in your header.inc.php file? If so, can you please post it?

Comment: the link to the page is [http://carolinawebfx.com/web182/mod10/guessingGame.php


  [1]: http://carolinawebfx.com/web182/mod10/guessingGame.php

I assume the session is saved. Browser shows an existing cookie while on page.
My live host is running php 5.3 and so is my localhost. That's the first thing I looked for actually.
As far as the header.inc file, It has no actual php, just a little javascript to position the cursor. Tried removing the js part, still didn't work. 
Like I said it's pretty basic.
I'll try using the var_dump() statement to see what it says.

Comment: Try `!is_numeric($guess)` instead of `!ctype_digit($guess)`. PHP docs say: "If an integer between -128 and 255 inclusive is provided, it is interpreted as the ASCII value of a single character–––". (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) This doesn't explain the localhost/server issue thought. Check the types of `$guess` and `$_POST['guess']`. They should be `string`s but if `$guess` is somehow `int` that could cause the failure.

Comment: If your sessions doesn't work on Fat Cow these might help: http://theedgeofall.com/journeys/2010/04/21/php-ini-issues-fat-cow-hosting/, http://www.fatcow.com/knowledgebase/beta/article.bml?ArticleID=1290, http://www.fatcow.com/knowledgebase/read_article.bml?kbid=7090

Comment: Alright, thanks. I changed it to !is_numeric, and added var_dump() for all 3 session variables. That returned NULL for the 'num' variable, int(0) for the 'count' variable, and NULL for the 'guess' variable (the user input). So clearly my session is not being saved? What's the deal? Seems like it should work the same as it did on my localhost. I tried to contact fatcow support to see if my settings needed changed, they just said my script has bugs.

Comment: thanks, ZZ-bb. I'll check those out.

Comment: Actually I was wrong the header.inc.php file does have the following php:   <title><?php echo $pageTitle ?></title>  That shouldn't matter I think. I tried using the session.save_path thing at the top of my code. It didn't help at all. When I put it above the session_start() function (as directed by FatCow tutorial), it rendered the page blank. When I put it below, it had no effect, same problem existed.

Comment: Should I try deleting the ";" ('uncommenting')? This seems like a stupid thing to have to do, but if it fixes it I'll try. How is this done? Is there a function that removes all the ";"? Maybe it's just best not to use FatCow if you plan to have sessions?

Comment: YAY! I fixed it! Or, rather, I fixed FatCow. Thank you all, especially ZZ-bb with those links. What I had to to was change the default php.ini script so that the session had a place to be stored. (Seems like that should've been preset but whatever). Tried to turn off register_globals but that screwed it up so I left it ON. Thanks for taking the time to help. You can have fun playing my little game program here: [link](http://carolinawebfx.com/web182/mod10/guessingGame.php). Thanks for taking time to help!

Answer (score 0):

(I'll add my comments as an answer since it helped in solving the issue.)

Apparently sessions do not work out of the box with Fat Cow hosting. Some links to see:

- http://theedgeofall.com/journeys/2010/04/21/php-ini-issues-fat-cow-hosting/
- http://www.fatcow.com/knowledgebase/beta/article.bml?ArticleID=1290
- http://www.fatcow.com/knowledgebase/read_article.bml?kbid=7090

B. Bulpett. I suggest you try and find a solution **not** using [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) since it's deprecated and will be removed from PHP 5.4.0 onwards.

Comment: Thanks! Ive shared this info with my colleagues that also use FatCow. Actually didn't need the register_globals after all. Good to know about its pending deprecation.